# How to add oauth based ui to zuul gateway?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

I am new to microservices, I am trying to create a sample application with microservice architectural style.

My scenario is that I have 2 microservices called customer and vendor which have spring security implemented in them.

In order to access these microservices, I need to pass two separate URL i.e

1. For customer: - http://localhost:8090/customer
2. For Vendor: -   http://localhost:8091/vendor

So I brought in Zuul as an API gateway to access these URL's.

The gateway properties file (`application.properties`) is:

```
eureka.client.enabled=false
server.port=8080
zuul.routes.customer.url=http://localhost:8090
zuul.routes.vendor.url=http://localhost:8091
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri= http://localhost:8090/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri= http://localhost:8091/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.id=client
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=secret
```

After implementing this I am able to access all URL with respect to customer and vendor but I am unable to access OAuth based url's.
So can anyone help me out to figure out how can I make my gateway to include the OAuth based token in it?

Below are the sample example and their output with respect to OAuth and their behavior with the gateway and without the gateway.

Example-1 without gateway URL: -

```
input URL: -

    http://localhost:8090/oauth/token?password=abcd&username=test5&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read%20write

Header: -
     Basic Auth
             userName : client
             password : secret

output: -
{
    "access_token": "522a6b21-19bb-4833-90be-69d0c02f220a",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 99999,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

Example-2 with gateway URL: -

input url: -

```
    http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?password=abcd&username=test5&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read%20write

Header: -
     Basic Auth
             userName : client
             password : secret

output: -
{
    "timestamp": 1506918637823,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

So can anyone help me out tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I have followed the below link to implement my gateway.
[Reference to API gateway implementation code](https://github.com/rpicloud/guide-zuul-api-gateway)

Thanks in advance.